# Compare values in third column in one file with value in another file

Tags: awk

I have two files.

File 1 has this format:

```
 f  55 SE 0 0 0
 re 13 SE 0 0 0
```

File 2 has this format:

```
fe 10  f
fe 02  h
fe 02  re
```

I need to first compare the files to see if the third column values of file 2 are present in the first column of file 1. If they are, I need the entire row, which contains the value present in both files, in file 1 to be printed to an output file. As shown in the example, some of the values in the third column of file 2 are not present in the first column of file 1. I have tried using awk but I am honestly new to programming and am not entirely sure how to go about this.

My expected output looks like this:

```
f 55 SE 0 0 0
re 02 SE 0 0 0
```

It should have the same format as file 1, it simply filters out the rows that do not have a first column value the same as the third column value of file 2.

Comment: It is always recommended to add expected sample output into your post too, also whatever you have tried add that too, as we all are here to learn, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding this solution as OP added expected output now.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$3]; next} $1 in a' File2 File1
```

---

Since you haven't posted sample output so couldn't test it, could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$3]=$1 OFS $2;next} ($1 in a){print $0,a[$1]}' Input_file2  Input_file1
```

Comment: i have updated my question. Unfortunately, that code did not produce any output.

Comment: @Ellie, kindly check my EDIT solution now and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Ahh , that worked perfectly! I was definitely over-thinking my code. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: the assignment `=$1 OFS $2;` is superfluous.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sorry to bug you again, but if file 1 were to be transpose (If I needed to extract columns now instead of rows) would this function also work?

Comment: @Ellie, this code is written only for the specific problem may not work for another one, you could better open a new thread for another question I will say.

Comment: @karakfa, could you please let me know the correct one, if possible could you please edit my post too, if needed, thank you.